# PHP preg_quote() and less-than sign

Tags: php

```
echo preg_quote("aaa<bbb");
```

should write:

```
aaa\<bbb
```

but I get:

```
aaa\
```

This is the only sign that makes problems.

Comment: Are you echoing this out to a browser window? If so, look at the page source not the browser screen output.  What you're probably seeing is half-rendered, broken HTML since the `<` isn't encoded as `&lt;`

Comment: I'm talking about the source code, at first I thought so too.

Comment: In the PHP intrepeter, it works exactly as expected for me: `php > echo preg_quote("aaa<bbb");
aaa\<bbb`

Comment: This is simplified example of what I need (but it doesn't match with just THIS sign):
preg_match('/'.str_replace("zzz", "<", preg_quote("azzzb")).'/', "aaa<bbb", $out); print_r($out);

Comment: You can check output of this code at this interpreter http://writecodeonline.com/php/
Here is output that I get on local server and on hosting.
It looks to me like a php bug.

Comment: in your internet explorer, right click the page then click view source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display it in browser what it just is, you could wrap it in `<pre>` tag.

```
echo '<pre>'.preg_quote("aaa<bbb").'</pre>';
```

Or you could use htmlspecialchars to escape the `<`.

```
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_quote("aaa<bbb"));
```

Comment: No, I need this for preg_match() as a pattern from a template.
I don't really understand how it can not to work if it's just a string.
This works: echo preg_quote("aaa<bbb").'>';
And this not: echo preg_quote("aaa<bbb").'';